# Getting SL4A (ASE) to GNU/Linux box

Tags: android, sl4a

Without emulator, is there a way to execute the scripts. as any other normal py code?
Tried to port, but /me gets :

```
droid = android.Android()
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/android.py", line 34, in __init__
self.conn = socket.create_connection(addr)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/socket.py", line 547, in create_connection
for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use a remote connection to your phone and execute the script local, see [RemoteControl](http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/wiki/RemoteControl) in the SL4A Wiki.